# Is there a method to display images to HTML pages outside the app folder for Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

The structure looks like this:

```
app
— base
——static
———-images
———-files
——other
data
—images
—files
```

I was storing images and files in the static folder and it was easily accessible through url_for(). However, I was required to store the items outside the app folder and I could not find a way to access these files.

Is there a way to route to folders outside app to display to HTML?

Comment: for rendering html templates , u can configure `template_folder` in flask app

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can include any location that you think is right and safe.
I recommend that you familiarize yourself with the [Instance Folder](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/#instance-folders).
The default location is './instance/var/'. However, by configuration it is possible to place this at any location that has the necessary access rights.

This simple example can be modified and extended depending on the requirements. Access to another folder outside of the application root directory, within the instance path, is made possible. The behavior is according to the static folder. Subdirectories are therefore also possible.

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, send_from_directory
from werkzeug.security import safe_join

app = Flask(__name__,
    instance_relative_config=True,
    instance_path='/path/to/instance/folder'
)
app.config.from_mapping(
    DATA_FOLDER='data'
)

try:
    os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
except OSError:
    pass

@app.route('/')
def index():
    filenames = os.listdir(safe_join(
        app.instance_path,
        app.config.get('DATA_FOLDER', 'data')
    ))
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())

@app.route('/data/<path:filename>')
def data(filename):
    target = safe_join(
        app.instance_path,
        app.config.get('DATA_FOLDER', 'data')
    )
    return send_from_directory(target, filename)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      {% for filename in filenames -%}
      <li><a href="{{ url_for('data', filename=filename) }}">{{ filename }}<a></li>
      {% endfor -%}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```